# Passing data view-template-view in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm handling input file in my project and passing processed text to another html for user approvement

```
def vm_to_csv_upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        some code here
        br_work_string = re.sub('\\n', '<br>', work_string)
        page_text = 'Here\'s what gonna be uploaded to crowdin:<br><br><br>' + br_work_string + '<br><br><br>Is that okay?'
        return render(request, 'upload_crowdin_check.html', {'page_text': page_text, 'csv_text': work_string})
```

On this page i show passed data:

```
<body>
    <div id="text_check">
        {% autoescape off %}
        {{ page_text }}
        {% endautoescape %}
    </div>
    <form action="/crowdin_approve/" method="POST" value={{ csv_text }} id="csv">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" value="Okay">
    </form>
</body>
```

And trying to pass it to another view to process it again.

```
def crowdin_approve(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return HttpResponse(request.POST)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('nope')
```

But only thing i get is csrfmiddlewaretoken. What am i doing wrong? How should i pass {{ csv_text }} value to view? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the content of `csv_text` using an hidden input field:

```
<form action="/crowdin_approve/" method="POST" id="csv">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="csv_text" value="{{ csv_text }}">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" value="Okay">
</form>
```

Then you can access it in the view this way:

```
def crowdin_approve(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        csv_text = request.POST.get('csv_text', None)
```